# Use loadkeys to disable/enable ctrl-alt-del reboot

Tags: reboot

In the [ubuntu man page for reboot](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man2/reboot.2.html), there is a section that reads,

> The   reboot()   call  reboots  the  system,  or  enables/disables  the  reboot  keystroke
> (abbreviated  CAD,  since  the  default  is  Ctrl-Alt-Delete;  it  can  be  changed  using
> loadkeys(1)).

Litterally running `loadkeys(1)` doesn't seem right.  How exactly do I disable the CAD reboot?

Comment: You should look into loadkeys command

Comment: See `man 5 keymaps`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might be a late answer but you can disable reboot when hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> by executing both commands below

```
sudo systemctl mask ctrl-alt-del.target
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```